# How to recognize sounds (e.g. Clap Hands) with Flash?

Tags: flash, speech-recognition

What is the easiest way to recognize if my website visitor has just clapped hands twice?

My idea: Flash is capable of using the microphone if allowed by the user.

Comment: you might want to start by looking into sound and pattern recognition and signal analysis, this is much more than just a programming question

Comment: "this is much more than just a programming question", programming is also recognise your challenges and provide ways to solve them. Unless you are a code monkey, that likes sticking to the code. Programming is not only writing code

Comment: Federico: How do you propose we direct message you?  There is no feature on SO for that.  Furthermore, any implementation details can be included in the answer to the question.  There's no reason that implementations should be shared with you alone.

Comment: @José, maybe I didn't make my self clear, but I never implied anything negative in my comment.  I only meant to say that the problem he is asking is so involved that simply expecting someone to 'implement the solution' and send it to him is not a reasonable expectation.  He should be trying it himself and asking more specific questions, like what kind of algorithm should he use to detect clapping in a sound file, or the best way to get data from a low quality microphone, etc.

Comment: @belgariontheking: Ups. You are right. No direct messages supported here. So just write a comment.
@yx: I just thought, that if someone could implement this easily, while I would have to learn the whole background, why should I not hire someone to do this job for me?
Therefor I wrote: "if anyone is also able to implement the solution", not "If you implement the solution for me..."
You know: Time is money.
And besides, someone already gave a helpful answer to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please atleast look at [this tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/microphone.htm) on Flash and the Microphone.